Spivak "Calculus" understanding authors intend.

As a matter of fact, it is impossible to find a continuous f such that
$(f(z))^2 =z$ for  all $z$. In fact, it is even impossible for $f(z)$
to be defined for all $z$ with $|z|=1$. To  prove this by
contradiction, we can assume that $f(1)=1$ (since we could always
replace $f$ by $-f$). Then we claim that for all $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$
we have
$$f(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
The argument for this is left to you (it is a standard type of least upper bound  argument).

Since by assumption $(f(z))^2=z$, we have $(f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^2=\cos\theta+i\sin \theta$
Applying the trigonometric identities $\cos 2\theta = \cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$ and $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ we get $$(f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^2=\cos\theta+i\sin \theta
=\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}+2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos \frac{\theta}{2}
=(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2})^2$$
But this only implies that $$f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)= \cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$ or $$f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)= -\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$
I can't understand how to use  the least upper bound  argument which author suggested to eliminate the last possibility

Consider the nonempty set of $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ for which the first equality holds. (Why is it nonempty?)

note that $f(1)=1$ and look at $f(-1)$ which is either $i$ or $-i$; but $f$ is never purely imaginary except at $-1$ (since $f(z)=ci, c \in \mathbb R$ means $z=-c^2$) so $\Re f$ doesn't vanish on $[0, \pi)$ nor on $(\pi, 2\pi]$; by continuity we have $\Re f >0$ there but now taking the limit at $\pi$ from both sides gives you a contradiction to continuity

You know $S={ \theta \mid f(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = \cos \frac {\theta}{2} + i \sin \frac{\theta}{2} }$ is non-empty because $0 \in S$.  If $S \neq [0, 2 \pi)$, choose the least upper bound of the set $T= { \theta \mid \forall \alpha \lt \theta ~(\alpha \in S) }$.  Use continuity of $f$ to show $T= \varnothing$.

Let $B = \{ \tau \in [0,2\pi) \mid f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \text{ for all } \theta \in [0,\tau] \}$.
In particular, if $\tau \in B$, then $f(\cos\tau+i\sin\tau) = \cos\frac{\tau}{2}+i\sin\frac{\tau}{2}$. So let us show that $B = [0,2\pi)$.
Since $B$ is non-empty ($0 \in B$), the least upper bound $b$ of $B$ is contained in $[0,2\pi]$.
Claim 1. $b > 0$.
Assume $b = 0$. Then for each $n$ there exists $\theta_n \in [0,\frac 1 n]$ such that $f(\cos\theta_n+i\sin\theta_n) = -\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}$, Clearly $\theta_n \ne 0$ and $\theta_n \to 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, we get $f(1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\cos\theta_n+i\sin\theta_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty} (-\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}) = -1$ which is a contradiction.
Claim 2. $[0,b) \subset B$.
Let $c \in [0,b)$. Since $c < b$, the number $c$ is not an upper bound of $B$ which means that there exists $\tau \in B$ such that $c < \tau$. We know that $f(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \text{ for all } \theta \in [0,\tau]$. Since $[0,c] \subset [0,\tau]$, we see that $c \in B$.
Claim 3. $b = 2\pi$.
Assume $b < 2\pi$. Then for each $n$ there exists $\theta_n \in [b,b+\frac 1 n]$ such that $f(\cos\theta_n+i\sin\theta_n) = -\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}$. Since $\theta_n \to b$, we conclude $f(b) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\cos\theta_n+i\sin\theta_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty} (-\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}) = -\cos\frac{b}{2}-i\sin\frac{b}{2}$.
On the other hand, there exists a sequence $(\tau_n)$ in $[0,b)$ such that $\tau_n \to b$. We conclude $f(b) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\cos\tau_n+i\sin\tau_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty} (\cos\frac{\tau_n}{2}+i\sin\frac{\tau_n}{2}) = \cos\frac{b}{2}+i\sin\frac{b}{2}$.
This contradiction proves $B= [0,2\pi)$.
